# error on PS5 when I try to load a PS4 saved game

Tags: ps4, ps5, assassins-creed-valhalla

When I try to play Assassin's Creed Valhalla PS5 version in the main menu it shows me my saved games from PS4, but when I choose a saved game and tried to play the game crashes and sends this message:

**You cannot continue using this game or application. The data is corrupted. Delete it from your PS5 and then re-download it from your library**

This is my troubleshooting without success

I erased all the data of the game in my PS5 system (system ⇾ storage ⇾ saved games data) for both versions (PS4 & PS5) and then play in my PS4 a saved game from AC Valhalla, save the game, load the data in the PS cloud,  back to my PS5 and load the data from the PS cloud, then I try to play this load game but still happens the same, this situation only happens with the PS5 version, with the PS4 version I can play without problems the saved game in PS5

Did it happen to someone else? Could you help me fix this problem?

Comment: At this point it will probably be better to just contact Ubisoft support. By the way, does it shows any error code?

Comment: No, I don't have any error code, only the text of my question, but now I will try with Ubisoft support